# Problema al cargar datos con JQuery en una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvc, controller

Buenos días a todos.

Tengo el problema al cargar unas filas en una tabla, tengo que dar varias veces clic al enlace que muestra esta tabla para que aparezcan las filas.

```
$("#btnlogin").click(function (){
var user = $("#user").val();
var pass = $("#pass").val();
var opcion = 1;
$.post("personaCTR",{user:user,pass:pass,opc:opcion},function (data) {
    var login = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);  
    if(login.op==1){
        $("#modalLogin").modal("hide");
        if(login.rolid==1){
            $("#gestion li:last").after(
                    "<li class='usu'><a class='page-scroll' onclick='adm()' href='#jsp'>Administradores</a></li><li class='usu'><a class='page-scroll' onclick='usu();' href='#jsp'>Usuarios</a></li><li class='usu'><a class='page-scroll' onclick='pro();' href='#jsp'>Productos</a></li><li class='usu'><a class='page-scroll' onclick='ven();' href='#jsp'>Ventas</a></li>");
        }
    }else{
        document.getElementById('alerta').style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

});

Vuelvo a decir que debo dar varios clics para que se pueda cargar bien la tabla con los datos.

```
function adm(){
$.get("administradorCTR",{opc:1},function (data, status){
    var pro = JSON.parse(data); 
    $("#tablita_administrador").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    $.each(pro, function (index, obj){
        console.log(obj);
        $("#tablita_administrador tr:last").after(
            "<tr><td>"+obj.perid+"</td><td>"+obj.peruser+"</td><td>"+obj.perpassword+"</td><td>"+obj.adminombre+" "+obj.admiapellido+"</td><td>"+obj.admidni+"</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' id='modificar_admi' name='"+obj.perid+"'>"+
            "<i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='eliminar_admi' name='"+obj.perid+"'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></tr>");
    });  
});
$('#jsp').load('look/administradores.jsp');
```

}

Agradecería sus ayudas, Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pregunto, por qué simplemente no utilizás ajax? haciendo esto

```
<stcript type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     $.ajax({
          url: "/tu/url",
          type: "get / post",  //alguno de los dos
          dataType: "json",
          succes: function(data){
             $.each(data, function(i, v){
                  $("#tutabla").append(<tr><td>v.valor1</td><td>v.valor2</td></tr>)
              })
          }
       })
   })
```

Ese caso es valido para hacer esto también..

```
$(function () {
 $("#boton").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
      url: "/tu/url",
      type: "get / post",  //alguno de los dos
      dataType: "json",
      succes: function(data){
         $.each(data, function(i, v){
              $("#tutabla").append(<tr><td>v.valor1</td><td>v.valor2</td></tr>)
          })
      }
    })
  })
```

})